# flask-paginate does not show pagination buttons

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, python-2.7, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

I checked out [flask-paginate](https://github.com/lixxu/flask-paginate) and also install it with `pip install flask-paginate`. However, I do not get any errors with the example app, but pagination does not appear see [screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGMy5.png). Why do I not get the pagination buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the paginate output through the Jinja `|safe` filter:

Per the documentation (http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/):

```
{{ pagination.info|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this and the default offset to flask-paginate was 10, adding 1 entry showed me the pagination.links. Hope this helps...